# Extremely slow wireless file transfer on specific computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, file-transfer

I have a Linksys E4300 router which works great. I bought an HTPC with a [Gigabyte E350N](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4264#ov) and plugged a [TP-LINK TL-WN723N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TL-WN723N).

The HTPC is about 5mts from the router and without any wall in the middle. The wireless signal is all bars but when I try to transfer a file from an external USB hard drive connected to the router I get about 100 KBps... 
While on an old 2007 HP laptop, from the same place, same file, I get about 7 MBps (which is also what I get on my wired desktop computer). So it's definitely not the router or hard-drive or anything related to it.

Both the laptop and the HTPC have Windows 7 x64 installed from the same DVD.

Could it really be the TP-LINK so slow? or is some misconfiguration on the HTPC windows?

**UPDATE**

I have plugged the wireless stick to my notebook and use that to connect to the wireless network. I got the same 7 MBps speed so it's definitely something about the HTPC configuration.

Another thing to consider is that in the HTPC using the stick I get full speed internet download (about 1.5 MBps which is my max speed cause I have a 12 Mbit connection). So really it doesn't make sense that the HTPC is able to download faster from the internet than from the local network....

Comment: Yes; the hardware compared to the other two devices is half as good

Comment: What do you mean? The old laptop is an intel dual core with 4gb RAM and the HTPC is also a dual core but AMD and 8gb RAM.

Comment: Have you installed all BIOS and driver updates?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, all the latest from Gigabyte site.

Comment: Try putting your Wi-Fi USB dongle on a USB extension cable (or use a normal USB cable and hub if you have one) to get it away from possible RF noise from the HTPC, and get it out of your media cabinet and away from instructions.

Comment: I was talking about the router ( 450 Mbs ) and the 802.11 150Mbs device

Comment: @Ramhound It's not the stick, read my update. I tried it on another computer and I got a lot more speed. 150Mbs is enough to get more than 100 KBps on a file transfer....

Comment: Depending on the OS you are using, try checking the advanced power settings for the device and see if it is on a power-saving mode or limited functionality.

Comment: @wiz3kid No, I've already switched it to "full performance".